# TeXStudio: file system view?

Tags: texstudio

I made quite a lot of searches for "texstudio files folders", "textsudio file system", "... directory structure", "files", etc. and could not find anything.

I am using texstudio. The main .tex file in a folder with a ./pdfs and ./imgs subfolders. I would like to see files and folders, basically wwhat is on file system starting from the root folder of the latex prohject, inside of texstudio (like, for example, I can when using Visual Studio Code).

Is this possible?

Comment: There is an open feature request about this: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/639. The fact that the issue is open probably means that it is not possible yet.